# Writing text file in Python produces empty file

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I have to keep track of model performance across different version releases. I'm trying to create and write a text file that contains some lines of text that signal turbulences in the model performance. This is the function I wrote (it contains some auxiliary functions but these are not relevant for my question):

```
def alarm(cell_line, conc, full_model_id, metric, treshold):
    v_model_results = get_model_across_versions(cell_line, conc, full_model_id)
    v_model_results2 = v_model_results.reset_index()[metric]
    percentages_list = calculate_percentages(v_model_results2)
    length = len(percentages_list)
    res = []
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(length): if (percentages_list[i] < -treshold):
                f.write("The percentage treshold between the versions v" + str(i+13) + " and v" + str(i+14)+ " is exceeded for the metric " + metric +". There is a drop of " + str(-percentages_list[i]) + " percent." + "\n")
                print("The percentage treshold between the versions v" + str(i+13) + " and v" + str(i+14)+ " is exceeded for the metric " + metric +". There is a drop of " + str(-percentages_list[i]) + " percent.")
            else:
                print("No significant turbulence in performance between the versions v" + str(i+13) + " and v" + str(i+14)+ " for the metric " + metric + ".")
        f.close()
```

When I apply the above function to an example all the messages are printed correctly and it indeed generates a text file `results.txt`, but this file is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't explicitly close files that you are managing with a context manager (`with`).

Comment: also, creating a function but never calling it is not very useful

Comment: simply delete the `f.close()` and it will work

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the *right* `results.txt` file?  Since you're opening a bare filename, the file will be located in the current working directory - wherever that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open('results.txt', 'w')` will open the file and overwrite any data in it. This could be causing your problem.

Try `open('results.txt', 'a')`. To append new text instead of overwritting.

Also, you don't need to include `f.close()`. The with statement handles that all for you.